# How do I scroll to the cursor position in an NSTextView?

Tags: macos, scroll, nstextview

How can I make programmatically an `NSTextView` scroll to the cursor position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
NSUInteger cursorPosition;
cursorPosition = [[[self.textView selectedRanges] firstObject] rangeValue].location;
[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(cursorPosition, 0)];
```